# ZF2 form radio/checkbox with text input

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I have a form in which a user can select one or more tags. But when there are no tags which apply he/she must add one or more of their own in a separate input field with the type:text.

How can i do this in zf2 so that the required validator sees it as one element?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The zf2 documentation has a pretty good example [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#adding-new-elements-dynamically).

You basically create a form collection and add a Element with a **placeholder** option. You can just apply any validator to it, too. I'd suggest writeing it within an external .js file and use jQuery or any other javascript framework, though.

Answer (score 0):

i needed something similar, but couldn't find anything in zend (didn't look to far), for tagging you can use `selec2` it has a nice tagging support,

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

or you can write your own custom Element...